# What does <this> mean in TypeScript generics?

Tags: typescript, express, generics

We use `express` with TypeScript in our app. I came across their type definitions and was wondering what the following means:

```
export interface IRouter extends RequestHandler {
    all: IRouterMatcher<this>;
}
```

[image]

In particular, the `IRouterMatcher<this>`.

I read the docs a few times and couldn't find anything mentioning this use case. And it's pretty hard to search for `<this>` in either SO or the web as the angle brackets usually get stripped.

Comment: Playing around in the TypeScript playground, it looks like `this` refers to the interface itself (in this case, `IRouter`).

Comment: @FrankModica I think I see what you mean. Looking at the `IRouterMatcher<T>` interface I see the signature is `(path: PathParams, ...handlers: RequestHandler[]): T;` (one of them - uses overloading). So, the `<T>` for `IRouterMatcher<T>` would be whatever the type of `this` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the current available type.

This might also be the subtype of the overridden class or interface.

See also *Polymorphic this types* in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Example:

```
class Calculator {
    a: number;
    add(): this {
        a++;
        return this;
    } 
}

class AdvancedCalculator {
    substract(): this {
         a--;
         return this;
    } 
}

new AdvancedCalculator()
   .add() // returns AdvancedCalculator as "this" 
   .substact() // it compiles!
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I am quite familiar with your construct of returning the object for method chaining. However, your example does not use `<this>` in a generic type... that's the part I am a little fuzzy on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `<this>`, in your example, refers to the type that is currently implementing the interface.  For example if a class named TestClass implemented IRouter, then the functions that return `IRouterMatcher<this>` would return an `IRouterMatcher<TestClass>`.

After doing some more research, using `<this>` might be functionally equivalent to saying `<T extends IRouter>` such as `all: IRouterMatch<T extends IRouter>`.  Using `this` might just be a shorter way to express the same thing.